# How to use git clone https repository without user name and password (bash on windows)?

Tags: git, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm new to the bash shell on windows.  I installed git, and I need to clone a private http repository.  I'm getting prompted for my user name and password. I understand I should use a git credential manager to securely store my credentials.  How would I go about doing this with the WSL?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at this question and the top answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github

Comment: Please provide us with more information. Do you have a SSH key or are you able to get your SSH key onto the server? If not I personaly dont know the way to bypass the username/password.

Comment: Thanks Derek.  I saw that, but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to when using bash for windows :(  I tried the command line, but it didn't appear to work

Comment: Sasa, no SSH key.  I like what Derek suggested, but I've been unsuccessful in getting it to work

Answer (score -1):

I actually just went through this same thing with setting it up on Windows 10. I followed this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/) to set it up and it all works fine for me to use all git commands in Windows Git Bash.

Comment: That is a github how to and the qestion is for the git and a private repo.

Comment: Using Windows Git Bash, I was able to use the credential helper.  Using Bash for Windows (linux subsystem), I wasn't able to get it working.